# Is $(\log(n))!$ a polynomially bounded function?

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, computational-complexity, factorial

Is the following statement true? How would you prove it?


i.e. Is it a polynomially bounded?

$$
\lceil \lg(n) \rceil ! \in O(n^k)
$$

How about
$$
\lceil \lg \lg(n) \rceil ! \in O(n^k)
$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know Sterling's approximation?  That's actually enough to answer both questions.

Answer (score 6):

Hint #1: Look at [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Hint #2: $\ln n^{\ln n} = \left(e^{\ln \ln n}\right)^{\ln n} = e^{\left(\ln n\cdot \ln\ln n\right)} = ?$  (Note that I use $\ln$ rather than $\lg$, but the bases of the logs don't make any real difference here - convince yourself of that, though!)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I think the second step of the second hint should read $\left(e^{\ln\circ\ln(n)}\right)^{\ln(n)}$.

Comment: @EulCan You're not wrong. Fixed!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki finally, what is the answer. are they polynomially bounded or not??

Answer (score 2):

**A start:** By considering $(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots \cdot w)(w\cdot (w-1) \cdot (w-2)\cdots \cdot 1)$, we can show that 
$(w!)^2\ge w^{w}$, and therefore
$w!\ge w^{w/2}$.

Let $w=\log n$.

For the second problem, the upper bound $w!\le w^w$ (for $w\gt 0$) is enough.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's not at all incorrect, and it's relevant to the original post.  (This is a way of getting a simpler approximation than Stirling's that's good enough to do the job here).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Someone downvoted both answers on the page; I doubt you or Andre would give wrong answers so I'm guessing it's just spiteful.